# Action Listener is not getting fired on click of button

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am using a action listener event to upload documents on click of button. But when I click on the button it is not getting into the `actionlistener` method. But once I refresh the page the event starts working.

I tried invoking the event using `phaseId` as well ,but it is not working.

Let me know if I can do this in any other way.

My `xhtml`:

```
   <ace:fileEntry id="fileEntryForDocUpld" disabled="#{triggerRequestFormBean.disableDocUpload}" 
                                                                absolutePath="#{triggerRequestFormBean.uploadDirectory}"
                                                                maxFileCount="10"
                                                                maxFileCountMessage="Limited to 10 files uploaded concurrantly."
                                                                fileEntryListener="#{triggerRequestFormBean.uploadDocumentListener}"
                                                                required="false" useOriginalFilename="true"
                                                                useSessionSubdir="true" immediate="true" >
                                                            </ace:fileEntry>

    <h:commandButton id="upldDoc"
                                                                disabled="#{triggerRequestFormBean.disableDocUpload}"  
                                                                actionListener="#{triggerRequestFormBean.docUploadListener}"
                                                                partialSubmit ="true"
                                                                value="Load" styleClass="buttonStyle" 
                                                                title="Load" >
                                                            </h:commandButton>

**java class -**

public void uploadDocumentListener(final FileEntryEvent event) {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info(LOG_METHOD_ENTER);
        }
        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.ANY_PHASE) {
            event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
            event.queue();
        }
        getBaseBean().getErrorMessagesList().clear();

        try {
            setFile(FileUploadUtility.fileEntryUploadListener(event));
            if (getFile() != null) {

                String fileNameWithExtension = getFile().getName();
                int endIndex = fileNameWithExtension.lastIndexOf(ConstantKeys.DOT);
                String uploadedDocFormat = fileNameWithExtension.substring(
                        endIndex + 1, fileNameWithExtension.length()).toLowerCase();

                String docFormats = factory.getMessage(ConfigKeys.EDM_SUPPORTING_FILE_FORMAT);
                List<String> supportedFormatList = Arrays.asList(docFormats.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                if(!supportedFormatList.contains(uploadedDocFormat)){
                    getBaseBean().getErrorMessagesList().add(
                            messageFactory.getMessage(ERROR_SELECT_VALID_FILE_FORMAT)); 
                } else {
                    setDocLocation(getFile().getName());
                    setPercentDoc(100);
                    final TriggerRequestDocumentDataBean docBean = new TriggerRequestDocumentDataBean();
                    docBean.setTrgrRqstDocNm(appendTimestampToFile(getFile()
                            .getName()));

                    //Throw Error incase if the document name is greater than 60 after appending timestamp 
                    if(docBean.getTrgrRqstDocNm()!=null && docBean.getTrgrRqstDocNm().length()>60){
                        getBaseBean().getErrorMessagesList().add(
                                messageFactory.getMessage(ERROR_PLEASE_SELECT_FILE_NAME_BELOW_60CHAR)); 
                        return;
                    } 
                    docBean.setTrgrRqstAttach(FileUploadUtility
                            .readFileAsBytes(getFile()));
                    final CommonBO commonBO = (CommonBO) FacesUtils
                            .findBean(COMMON_BO);
                    final Date currentDt = commonBO.getSysdate();
                    docBean.setCreatedByEmpNbr(getLoginUserIdAsLong());
                    docBean.setCreatedDt(currentDt);
                    docBean.setLastUpdtByEmpNbr(getLoginUserIdAsLong());
                    final Employee employee = commonBO
                            .populateEmployeeDetails(getLoginUserIdAsString());
                    if (employee != null) {
                        final StringBuilder sbEmpName = new StringBuilder(employee
                                .getFirstNm()).append(SPACE).append(
                                employee.getLastNm());
                        docBean.setLastUpdtBy(sbEmpName.toString());
                    }
                    docBean.setLastUpdtDt(currentDt);
                    docBean.setNewRecord(true);
                    if (CommonUtil.isListNotEmpty(getTrfDocList())) {
                        getTrfDocList().add(0, docBean);
                    } else {
                        getTrfDocList().add(docBean);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {

        }

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info(LOG_METHOD_EXIT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will be invoke on click of File Upload button from UI
     */
    public String docUploadListener(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.ANY_PHASE) {
            event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
            event.queue();
        }       

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info(LOG_METHOD_ENTER);
        }

        try {
            if (getFile() == null) {
                getBaseBean().getErrorMessagesList().add(
                        messageFactory.getMessage(ERROR_PLEASE_UPLD_DOC));
            }

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {

        }

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info(LOG_METHOD_EXIT);
        }
        /*JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance(), "window.location.reload();");*/
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share which listener is not being invoked here. Is it uploadDocumentListener or docUploadListener ?

Comment: both ...nothing is getting invoked

Comment: @Balus C - I could not find any thing indicated in the duplicate question that I am missing . Also , after refreshing the page , it works ..Why is so ..can I call the refresh from UI itself as on the first click it is not getting into any method ??

Comment: This question is unanswerable. There are too many probable causes in the information provided so far which you have nowhere explicitly excluded from being the cause. If you create a [mcve], it will be immediately visible. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info